# Adding a color-picker toolbar like mspaint's

Tags: mfc, color-picker

I want to add a color picker in my preferences dialog that is like mspaint's.
[image]

Is this possible to do with MFC? I'm using VC6 because the project was started on it a long time ago and now it can't be ported, so I can't use new MFC classes.

Comment: The current version of Paint (on Windows 7) has implemented the color picker as part of its Ribbon control. You don't have access to a Ribbon in VC 6, and creating one would be an unbelievable amount of work. I don't think any of the 3rd-party Ribbon control libraries still support VC 6. However, you *can* create a color picker toolbar like that found in *earlier* versions of Paint. It's actually quite easy. Is that acceptable to you?

Comment: Yes, of course, I was using this screenshot because I'm on Win7. I actually don't need anything fancy, and I'll probably settle for a single rectangle that shows CColorDialog (which is available for VC6 too :) when you click on it, I was just asking this question in case there's a common control just for that I've somehow missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of pieces to this puzzle. First is the multi-row toolbar-like functionality. The second is the color picker that gets invoked when you click "Edit Colors".

The first *can* be imitated (to a degree) with a multi-row tool bar. I seem to recall VC6's CToolBar having some issues with multi-row toolbars, but I'm not sure whether that may have been fixed in an service pack (it kind of seems like it might have, but I don't remember for sure).

If you don't like that (it won't look much like the original), you'd be pretty much stuck with creating your own control and putting it into a CToolBar. As long as you only want to imitate the control exactly as-is, that won't be terribly difficult -- you'll basically pass the control an array of color numbers, and when there's a click, it'll send a notification message with the chosen color number (or the index of the color number, if you prefer). The math for that is pretty easy as long as you stick with a fixed layout, but if you want to support changing the layout, it can get a lot more difficult in a hurry.

For the second part, one good starting point would probably be Hans Deitrich's [`XColorSpectrumCtrl`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/XColorSpectrumCtrl.aspx).

Comment: I also don't remember if there was a service pack that fixed multi-row toolbars, but embedding a dialog into a toolbar works flawlessly in VC 6. If I remember correctly, this is how the pre-Ribbon versions of Paint created the color picker, as well. This would be pretty trivial to implement, even in an older project.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible. However, unless you can find some existing code, you may need need to implement owner draw yourself to get this appearance.

There is a color picker control, `CMFCColorPickerCtrl`, which I haven't used. But I don't believe it does what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using VC6, and the project absolutely can't be ported to a newer Visual Studio, unfortunately.

Comment: @satuon: Did it ever occur to you to put details like that in your question to begin with? As you've just observed, it does change the answers.

Comment: Again, you can absolutely do this. But you may have to write it yourself. Note that the image you posted is part of a ribbon bar. If you are using VC6 then you don't even have a ribbon control to use. That means it's probably going to be a lot of work.