# How to add color picker like ms paint using mfc

Tags: colors, mfc, picker

I want to add a color picker like in MS Paint in the client area of dialog using MFC in VS 2013. We can create it using color dialog but it will look different. Thanks for help in advance.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Can you allow the user to select colours or not? The visual representation is not as important.

Answer (score 1):

This is the colors dialog used in my program:

[image: Colors Dialog]

My code is as simple as:

```
pcrColour = (COLORREF*)m_cbBkColour.GetItemDataPtr(m_iBkClrIndex);
CColorDialog dlgColour( *pcrColour, CC_SOLIDCOLOR, this);
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and it has a Community Edition for free. Can't you use that? The colour window is exactly the same as Paint on Windows 10.

Comment: Andrew, i want that above color dialog should be look same like ms paint.currently , i am not able to add same image with my question but i am giving you a link where you can see the image .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718381/adding-a-color-picker-toolbar-like-mspaints

Comment: If you click Edit Colours then it shows the same window. What you show is not a colour dialog. That is part of the ribbon control. You can roll your own window easy enough to look like that